# Visual Studio 2010 MSTest can't debug referenced assembly

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010, mstest

I wrote an unit-test using MSTest for my Application which uses functionality from a referenced assembly (ExpressionSerializer in this case).

It fails because of an exception I already fixed and it runs if I wrap the test in a console application instead of a TestMethod.

The curious thing is that I can't debug the assembly (step into, no symbols loaded) while using the test runner and again runs fine with the console application tester.

The assembly reference seems out dated using the test runner, but I can't find anything wrong with it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it by searching my harddive for the concerning assembly. Deleting every bit, were a lot more than I anticipated (temp folders), and rebuild it. Suddenly visual studios editor is aware of a missing assembly. But the references menu is fine (no warning, the assembly path is correct too).
Then removing readding the assembly (project reference ) does the trick.
Now the tests are running and no errors occur.